# How can I set a place a custom button on incomming call screen?

Tags: android

I went through some posts, but most of them discuss placing a image or a string with information on it.

I however need to place button that manipulates some call features.

Is there a method to do that universally works throughout all android distributions?

(I thought to pop up custom screen with my button above usual screen. Is that good idea, or is there more straightforward way to achieve this?)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

On stock devices there isn't going to be a legit way to put your own button "on" any portion of the Dialer application Activities (including incoming call screen). This kind of functionality would require the Dialer to explicitly provide an API for it. The stock system prevents applications in the background from placing their own clickable regions "on top of" whatever is currently in the foreground . (It's a good thing too, the bad reasons to do this far outweigh the legit ones.)

If you are wanting to do this you're going to have to look into building your own version of the OS that allows for it. OR potentially if you unlock your device enough to be able to install your own application that handles all of the functionality of the Dialer. Then you could provide an API for a third party application to do it(or just "bake in" your button to the Dialer) But I imagine that being able to get it all hooked up correctly to actually make your calls would be mighty difficult.